# How Can I get Array Images from Database Using API and convert it JSON array to show in HTML in Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, api

I want to get optionimage from my database using api then I want to push image value in json array so that I can display in HTML page.
My database structure is like below .
[image: this is screen shot of data where optionimage is located like this]

I have tried some way to get data but I am unable to optionimage properly and unable to convert it JSON array.
I was trying this one way as well

```
 data.survey.forEach(element => {
       var obj = {
       //is_attached_image: false,
       optionimage: element.optionimage,
      // _id: element.group_id._id
       }
      this.slideImages.push(obj);
       console.log(obj)
     });
```

but did not get appropriate result.

and I want to make such below format of optionimage so that I can play image loop.
but for that, I am bit confused that What I need to do to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear to what you are asking! Can you please be specific?

Comment: Actually I want to get optionimage from database  and database structure you can see in screen shot

Comment: What have you written so far on your html template?

Comment: the screenshot is from console! Would request to paste that JSON data in the question and expected array

Comment: No I did write anything in HTML so far but first I need to get in ts then will bind in  view page

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga Please provide the JSON instead Images

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, I did not make JSON format first i have to get this images then need to put JSON format

Comment: @PrashantPimpale  i was trying to get but its giving only one element result `this.optionimage = data.survey["5"].optionimage;`

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga From where that data comes from?

Comment: From Sever using API

Comment: Can you share that API? Will try with the real data

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga cause its quite hard to get data

Comment: you want api link

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga yes

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the array of images urls, you can generate your array in the following manner.

```
const unFlattenedImagesList = data.survey.map(element => {
  res = element.optionimage.map(obj => ({image: `http://xxxxxxxxxx:8087//SurveyImages/${obj[0]}`
  }));
  return res;
})
this.slideImages = [].concat(...unFlattenedImagesList));
```

I am not sure how exactly would you want to display the images, but you can use `*ngFor` to iterate, and pass the binded value to the `src` attribute, which will render the images in a `<div>`

```
<div *ngFor="let url of slideImages">
  <img src={{url.image}} alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: it is good but I am not able to get optionimage from database

Comment: hey, sorry about that, I have updated my answer. That will give the array of urls

Comment: I want to display in loop

Comment: Erm... Which part of my code are your referring to? .map() gives you the same thing too..

Comment: Oh, I just realised survey is an array.. Let me make some changes

Comment: hey, I have made some changes (again). Does it work now?

Comment: Hey, it should be `optionimage`, not optionImages. And what can you not find?

Comment: Also, can you use `JSON.stringify(data)` or something to print out the full json response for us?

Comment: How can  I create a Json object so that I can push image array value in that

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: here I am pushing these images in slideimages array now i want to create a json object of image array.
I have code like below :-


`if(element.optioinimages){
var slideimages = [];
element.optionimages.forEach((element,) =>{
slideimages.push({image:URL+element[0]});`
consol.log(slideimages)
}
 now I want to write code for json object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want exactly, but here is the answer of what I've understood

```
let URL = "http://<ip-address>:<port>/";
    let slideImages = [];
    data.survey.forEach(element => {
        if(Array.isArray(element.optionimage) && !empty(element.optionimage)) {
            element.optionimage.forEach(img => {
                slideImages.push({image: (URL+img[0])});
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: How can I create json object format so that I can push image array value in that format to display

Comment: The code I've share will create an object as you asked, like this

this.slideImages = [{}, {}]